# Pay for the purchase?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is "pay for the purchase" correct? Would it not mean something like "pay for the privilege of being able to buy something"? The context is a school newsletter and the phrase is as follows: "These funds were also used to pay for the purchase of an agenda for each student...". Thanks!

Comment: Don't overthink it.

Comment: @HotLicks that's very much against the spirit of this forum isn't it?  ;-)

Comment: As a corollary to Max's answer, technically if you were to parse this sentence literally you're right: "paying for the purchase of" something would be exchanging money for the ability to buy it.

Comment: The puzzle isn't the payment for the purchase. The puzzle is the purchase of *agendas*. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Pay for the purchase" is redundant, as "purchase" is a form of payment, so you've got two lots of paying in there.  I would just say

"These funds were also used to purchase an agenda for each student..."

or

"These funds were also used to pay for an agenda for each student..."

The second option seems more natural to me but i think either is fine.

Comment: The only issue I have with your answer is it's unusual to "buy" an "agenda", so "pay for an agenda" is apt to be confusing.  Your first wording makes it clearer that this is, in fact, what's being done, and it's not just a wording error.

Comment: It's not redundant. A purchase on credit, for example, is paid for later.

Comment: @MετάEd Hmm, good point.  "Pay for the purchase" still sounds redundant to me though.

Comment: @MετάEd Subtle distinction: a purchase on credit *is* paid for immediately, just not by the person making it. What is paid back later is the money the creditor put up for the item in place of the buyer.

Comment: If *pay for the purchase* is indeed redundant, then these too are redundant phrases: *my dad paid this month's rent*; *we fought a war*; * we ate dinner *; * she said a few confucius' sayings *;  *joined the weed-joint*. Using a redundantly longer sentence to avoid a not-so-redundant situation, is a greater redundant sin.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Ah, but it's not *pay for the purchase*; it's *pay for the purchase **of***.

Comment: @JohnClifford Not really. If I purchase equipment on 30 day credit terms, no money changes hands at that time. The debt is due 30 days later and hopefully paid at that time. You are thinking of a purchase with a credit card, I assume.

Comment: @MετάEd Probably am, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, *purchase* refers to both the payment and the acquisition of what was paid for.

> **Purchase** *verb*
>   Acquire (something) by paying for it; buy
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purchase)

In common usage, however, *purchase* is sometimes used as a noun, for which the acquisition aspect of the transaction dominates. Consider this refund policy found via a web search (I am not knowingly affiliated with Quality Diam):

> Please contact us if you are not satisfied with your purchase. We’ll let you know how to return your purchase. You may return the item in its original condition within 7 days of receiving it, for a full refund or an exchange.
>   [- QualityDiam](https://www.qualitydiam.com/pages/payment-vat-shipments-and-return-policies)

The *purchase* is said to be *returnable* in its original *condition*, with a full *refund* or exchange. This sounds very much like *purchase* is used as a reference (metonymic, perhaps) to the *goods* rather than the money.

> Is "pay for the purchase" correct?

Given the above, the natural reading is that *purchase* was used as a noun that referred to whatever was acquired. In that case, the phrase is correct and refers to the *payment* for whatever was acquired.

Comment: But would not the usage of "purchase of an agenda" preclude that specific meaning? Purchase by itself, sure, but "purchase of something"?

Comment: @PavelS I can see your point, but the natural reading still favours taking *purchase* to mean the acquisition in that context, rather than having the sentence refer to paying a purchasing agent.

Comment: @PavelS I had a discussion on this point, and Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 observed that since *purchase* follows the word *the*, it's not a verb there. So it's a noun in that context.